# How do customise a component's CSS selectors in FluentUI

Tags: reactjs, css-in-js, fluentui-react

I am trying to customise the behavior of an FluentUI component when it is hovered over (A Primary Button in this case). How do I customise CSS selectors when I am using Microsoft's React FluentUI library.

I tried this initially (This approach is deprecated now, in favor of the method where you add selectors as siblings)...

```
export const MyButton = (props: IButtonProps) => {
  const styles: IButtonStyles = {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      selectors : {
      ':hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#0000ff'
      }
    }
    },
  }

  return (
    <PrimaryButton styles={styles} {...props} />
  );
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
export const MyButton = (props: IButtonProps) => {
  const styles: IButtonStyles = {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
        ':hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#0000ff'
        }
      },
    }

  return (
    <PrimaryButton styles={styles} {...props} />
  );
}
```

Both approaches do not seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new `FluentUI` you can modify styles trough [specific props](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/f700ae31aceafa040df5ac61e094a1f73c2dd6c7/packages/react/src/components/Button/Button.types.ts#L372) based on button state:

```
export const MyButton = (props: IButtonProps) => {
  const styles: IButtonStyles = {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
    rootHovered: {
      backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
    },
  }

  return (
    <PrimaryButton styles={styles} {...props} />
  );
}
```

[Codepen working example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/BaREype).

On this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/f700ae31aceafa040df5ac61e094a1f73c2dd6c7/packages/react/src/components/Button/Button.types.ts#L372) you have `IButtonStyles` interface.